# how can i disable / enable all html buttons on a page using jquery

Tags: jquery, button

i have a lot of ajax calls and i want to make sure noone clicks any button during the ajax calls.  So i want to disable all buttons right before any ajax call and then reenable them after the return of the ajax call.  I know i can disable a single button like this:

```
 $("#buttonId").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
 $("#buttonId").removeAttr('disabled');
```

but what is the line in jquery to disable / reenable all buttons.  I DONT want to use select by class as i then have to remember to put a certain class name on all buttons.

NOTE: they are all NOT submit buttons.  Some are used for popping up dialogs, etc so

```
<input type="button" name="button" value="Show Popup" />
```

Comment: Not an actual answer, but I would suggest you put a transparent `<div>` on top of the whole page with a really high `z-index`, that way the user won't be able to interact with any element on the page, until the ajax call is done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first task is to define what a *button* means. Is it a submit buttons that you want to disable? If yes then you could use the [`:submit`](http://api.jquery.com/submit-selector/) selector if those are submit buttons:

```
$(':submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
...
```

If they are not all submit buttons then you could try a selector by a tag type:

```
$(':submit, :button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

And if you also can have a mix of tags that can be used as AJAX calls and normal calls you need to use a class selector to disambiguate them.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov - they are NOT all submit buttons

Comment: @ooo, what they might be other than submit buttons? Please define *button* in your case? Anchor, button, submit button, image button, a div with an onclick handler on it, ...? Without defining this you won't be able to write the proper selector.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov - i updated the question with an example button.  Many are submit buttons but many are also just type="button"

Comment: @ooo, next question: do you want to disable **all** submit buttons and **all** `input type="button"` buttons or only some of them? If you want to disable all of them you could use `$(':submit, :button')`. If there are buttons that you don't want to be disabled you need a CSS seelctor.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov - yes . . also, in your answer, wouldn't it be ":button" (instead of "button"), why would the syntax for submit and button be different?

Comment: @ooo, `$('button')` means that you will select all tags `<button>` whereas `$(':button')` means that you will select all tags `<button>` as well as all `<input type="button">`. Please read the documentation. All those selectors are explained pretty well. [`:submit`](http://api.jquery.com/submit-selector/), [`:button`](http://api.jquery.com/button-selector/)

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov - thanks for the clarification. i did go through the documentation but it wasn't working (thus the question). turns out it was a typo :(

Comment: As searching by attribute is ineficient id also make sure you cache your buttons into a variable on page ready.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try $(":button") ?  That would only do literal buttons though.  "input would be more broad, but would also match radio buttons.

Also, note that in your example, jQuery has to do the work of finding the button (or all buttons twice).  Chaining the function calls would avoid that problem.